# addSpecificOrientationListener on Android

Tags: android, react-native, device-orientation

In a React Native app, I'm using [react-native-orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation) to listen for orientation changes. If in landscape, I want to distinguish between landscape-right and landscape-left, so I use `addSpecificOrientationListener`, instead of `addOrientationListener`. But it doesn't seem to fire on an Android device.

Any idea how I can retrieve the specific orientation of the device in Android, using React Native?

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure you've added a [configChanges](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config) attribute to your `<activity>` in your AndroidManifest.xml, and make sure one of the values you specify is "orientation".

```
<activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      android:launchMode="singleTop"
      android:resizeableActivity="false"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

      ...

</activity>
```

This allows you to override the `onConfigurationChanged()` method in `MainActivity.java` as shown in the react-native-orientation README:

```
import android.content.Intent; // <--- import
    import android.content.res.Configuration; // <--- import

    public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
      ......
      @Override
      public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Intent intent = new Intent("onConfigurationChanged");
        intent.putExtra("newConfig", newConfig);
        this.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

      ......

    }
```